# saving xls as csv with libreoffice calc

Tags: command-line, libreoffice

I am using LibreOffice 3.5.7.2 Build ID: 350m1(Build:2) and would like to run LibreOffice calc from the terminal to open an .xls document and output to .csv. I can do this via the GUI by just opening the xls file and saving as csv and specifying the delimeter, but I would like to be able to do it via the terminal.

**Research I've done:**

when I run

```
> man libreoffice
```

I get:

```
SYNOPSIS
       libreoffice  [--accept=accept-string]  [--base]  [--calc] [--convert-to
       output_file_extension[:output_filter_name]
```

which has a command --convert-to output but I am not exactly sure how an example of that would look, I tried:

```
libreoffice --convert-to csv:writer_csv_Export --outdir /Data/ *.xls
```

as https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Starting_the_Software_With_Parameters/vi mentions but it is not working.

Comment: `libreoffice --headless --convert-to csv --outdir somedir *.xls` appears to work. `:writer_csv_Export` appears to be unnecessary, and it might also be a problem that `/Data/` means a directory called `Data` at the filesystem root, not in your home directory. Just omit `--outdir DIR` and you'll get the output in the current directory.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`libreoffice --headless --convert-to csv --outdir somedir *.xls` appears to work.

`--headless` stops Libreoffice from opening a window, so it just converts your files and then exits.

`:writer_csv_Export` after `csv` appears to be unnecessary.

It might also be a problem that `/Data/` means a directory called Data at the filesystem root, not in your home directory. Just omit `--outdir DIR` and you'll get the output in the current directory.

**Note:**

Close your xls/xlsx file before you run this command. If file is opened this command does not work.

Comment: is there a way to specify delimeter in command line ? I.E. instead of comma, pipe ?

Comment: There is an enhancement bug for this, so presumably not -> https://www.libreoffice.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=68786

Comment: ok no problem, hopefully they fix it that soon :-D

Comment: It exports only first sheet. Is there a way to export all sheets into separate files?

Comment: @GrzegorzWierzowiecki as explained in [this Ask Libreoffice answer](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/46466/how-to-convert-specific-sheet-to-csv-via-command-line/#) you'll have to first convert to XLSX and then to CSV via `xlsx2csv`. For everything else there are macros: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35988515/libreoffice-convert-all-specific-sheets-from-excel-to-csv) - [link](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=75404)

Comment: You have to close every LibreOffice window already open, otherwise the command will silently do nothing.

Comment: @EduardoDennis There is now documentation that explains how to specify the delimiter and other options: https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-GB/text/shared/guide/csv_params.html